# Why use dict.keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I recently wrote some code that looked something like this:

```
# dct is a dictionary
if "key" in dct.keys():
```

However, I later found that I could achieve the same results with:

```
if "key" in dct:
```

This discovery got me thinking and I began to run some tests to see if there could be a scenario when I *must* use the `keys` method of a dictionary.  My conclusion however is no, there is not.

If I want the keys in a list, I can do:

```
keys_list = list(dct)
```

If I want to iterate over the keys, I can do:

```
for key in dct:
    ...
```

Lastly, if I want to test if a key is in `dct`, I can use `in` as I did above.

Summed up, my question is: am I missing something?  Could there ever be a scenario where I *must* use the `keys` method?...or is it simply a leftover method from an earlier installation of Python that should be ignored?

Comment: @karthikr: in both cases, `for` creates an iterator object (the return value of the `iter()` function, which yields values in the sequence. Both cases return dictionary keys, with the difference that using `dict.keys()` requires an attribute lookup and function call *first*. Thus, it is less efficient.

Comment: @karthikr: add to that that in Python 2 `.keys()` creates a new list containing all the keys of the dictionary first.

Comment: Also, `k in d` (where d is a dictionary) has the potential to be much faster than `k in l` (where l is a list) as the latter does a linear search of the list, while the former does a hash lookup in the dictionary.  The hash lookup is O(1) while the list search is O(len(l)).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On Python 3, use `dct.keys()` to get a [*dictionary view object*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which lets you do set operations on just the keys:

```
>>> for sharedkey in dct1.keys() & dct2.keys():  # intersection of two dictionaries
...     print(dct1[sharedkey], dct2[sharedkey])
```

In Python 2.7, you'd use `dct.viewkeys()` for that.

In Python 2, `dct.keys()` returns a list, a copy of the keys in the dictionary. This can be passed around an a separate object that can be manipulated in its own right, including removing elements without affecting the dictionary itself; however, you can create the same list with `list(dct)`, which works in both Python 2 and 3.

You indeed don't want any of these for iteration or membership testing; always use `for key in dct` and `key in dct` for those, respectively.

Answer (score 14):

Source: [PEP 234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), [PEP 3106](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/)

Python 2's relatively useless `dict.keys` method exists for historical reasons. Originally, dicts weren't iterable. In fact, there was no such thing as an iterator; iterating over sequences worked by calling `__getitem__`, the element access method, with increasing integer indices until an `IndexError` was raised. To iterate over the keys of a dict, you had to call the `keys` method to get an explicit list of keys and iterate over that.

When iterators went in, dicts became iterable, because it was more convenient, faster, and all around better to say

```
for key in d:
```

than

```
for key in d.keys()
```

This had the side-effect of making `d.keys()` utterly superfluous; `list(d)` and `iter(d)` now did everything `d.keys()` did in a cleaner, more general way. They couldn't get rid of `keys`, though, since so much code already called it.

(At this time, dicts also got a `__contains__` method, so you could say `key in d` instead of `d.has_key(key)`. This was shorter and nicely symmetrical with `for key in d`; the symmetry is also why iterating over a dict gives the keys instead of (key, value) pairs.)

In Python 3, taking inspiration from the Java Collections Framework, the `keys`, `values`, and `items` methods of dicts were changed. Instead of returning lists, they would return views of the original dict. The key and item views would support set-like operations, and all views would be wrappers around the underlying dict, reflecting any changes to the dict. This made `keys` useful again.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not using Python 3, `list(dct)` is equivalent to `dct.keys()`. Which one you use is a matter of personal preference. I personally think `dct.keys()` is slightly clearer, but to each their own.

In any case, there isn't a scenario where you "need" to use `dct.keys()` per se.

In Python 3, `dct.keys()` returns a "dictionary view object", so if you need to get a hold of an unmaterialized view to the keys (which could be useful for huge dictionaries) outside of a `for` loop context, you'd need to use `dct.keys()`.

Comment: I agree with tom.  dct.keys() is more traditional and idiomatic python (e.g. it is `pythonic`).  Obtuse syntax tricks like `list(dct)` are more of a gimmick than an idiomatic usage - many times a noob python user would need to dig a little deeper to determine whether `list(dct)` returns a list of keys or a list of items.  dct.keys() is unambiguous and clear on initial inspection for anyone reading your code, even to a python noob.  `for key in dct` is fine as it is idiomatic python usage.

Comment: Technically `dct.keys()` is a "dictionary view object" in Python 3, not an iterator: `type(dct.keys())` is `<class 'dict_keys'>` while `type(iter(dct))` is `<class 'dict_iterator'>`.  (See Martijn's and user2357112's answers.)  Hence `next(iter(dct))` is OK but `next(dct.keys())` is not.

Comment: Ah, you're right of course, @torek. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

key in dict 
is much faster than checking
key in dict.keys()