# Parsing Multi-level Json in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following json:

```
{"sensors": 
        {"-KqYN_VeXCh8CZQFRusI": 
            {"bathroom_temp": 16,
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 8,
             "kitchen_temp": 18, 
             "living_temp": 17, 
             "power_bathroom": 0, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 0, 
             "power_kit_0": 0
        }, 
        "-KqYPPffaTpft7B72Ow9": 
            {"bathroom_temp": 20, 
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 19, 
             "kitchen_temp": 14, 
             "living_temp": 20, 
             "power_bathroom": 0, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 0
        },  
        "-KqYPUld3AOve8hnpnOy": 
            {"bathroom_temp": 23, 
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 40, 
             "kitchen_temp": 11, 
             "living_temp": 10, 
             "power_bathroom": 1, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 81, 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the python code that I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, url_for
from firebase import firebase
import os




firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://my-firebase-db-958b1.firebaseio.com/', None)
result = firebase.get('/Dublin-Ireland', None)
print "\n Json file created!\n"

data_temp = result.values()[0]

for key, value in data_temp.iteritems():
    print key
    print value
    print "\n\n"
```

With the current code, I'm able to view the keys "KqYN_VeXCh8CZQFRusI", "KqYPPffaTpft7B72Ow9", etc.. and the values for those keys which are:

```
{"bathroom_temp": 16,
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 8,
             "kitchen_temp": 18, 
             "living_temp": 17, 
             "power_bathroom": 0, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 0, 
             "power_kit_0": 0
        },
```

and

```
 {"bathroom_temp": 20, 
         "date": "02/08/2017", 
         "fridge_level": 19, 
         "kitchen_temp": 14, 
         "living_temp": 20, 
         "power_bathroom": 0, 
         "power_bathroom_value": 0
    },
```

I need to get the secondlevel keys and their values. I'm trying to have a file for each key ("bathroom_temp", "power_bathroom", etc...) and save all the corresponding values of those keys in the file.

For example, the file "bathroom_temp.txt" will have the values "16, 20, 23".

Comment: This should help you out - https://stackoverflow.com/q/17634177/2650427

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your JSON data in a variable:

```
data = {"sensors":
        {"-KqYN_VeXCh8CZQFRusI":
            {"bathroom_temp": 16,
             "date": "02/08/2017",
             "fridge_level": 8,
             "kitchen_temp": 18,
             "living_temp": 17,
             "power_bathroom": 0,
             "power_bathroom_value": 0,
             "power_kit_0": 0
        },
        "-KqYPPffaTpft7B72Ow9":
            {"bathroom_temp": 20,
             "date": "02/08/2017",
             "fridge_level": 19,
             "kitchen_temp": 14,
             "living_temp": 20,
             "power_bathroom": 0,
             "power_bathroom_value": 0
        },
        "-KqYPUld3AOve8hnpnOy":
            {"bathroom_temp": 23,
             "date": "02/08/2017",
             "fridge_level": 40,
             "kitchen_temp": 11,
             "living_temp": 10,
             "power_bathroom": 1,
             "power_bathroom_value": 81,
        }
    }
}
```

and then use a nested index address for getting the desired parameter:

```
kitchen_temp = data["sensors"]["-KqYN_VeXCh8CZQFRusI"]["kitchen_temp"]
print(kitchen_temp)
```

Comment: That works for the first set of data, i have hundreds of these, and the 1st level values (eg. KqYPPffaTpft7B72Ow9) is random and i do not have control over the name of this.